# Access list of lists by list identifier

Tags: python

I have a list of lists, for example:

```
l = [["A", "B", ["X", "Y", ["J", "K", "L"]]], ["D", "E", "F"]]
```

I know I can access each element by appending list index to element, for example, to access `"F"` I can do this:

```
l[1][2]
```

But I'd like to access it by a list of indexes:

```
indexes = [1, 2]
l[some_magic_with_indexes_variable] - which would be similar to l[1][2]
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that you have exactly two indices, you could just hardcode this as:

```
>>> l[indexes[0]][indexes[1]]
'F'
```

If you want to handle an arbitrarily long list of indices for an arbitrarily deep tree you'll need a loop:

```
>>> def traverse(tree, indices):
...     for i in indices:
...         tree = tree[i]
...     return tree
...
>>> traverse(l, indexes)
'F'
```